# Not able to read XML using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to read an `xml` file using Perl.

I tried `XML::Simple` and use `XML::LibXML`, but in both cases I am facing problems.

For `XML::Simple` it says

```
"keys on reference is experimental
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated"
```

when I use following

```
foreach my $k ({keys %$ref->{version}}) # output to conf
{
    print STDERR Dumper($k);
}
```

And for `XML::LibXML`, I am getting `"Can't locate XML/LibXML/Error.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::LibXML::Error module)"`.

When I tried to install `LibXML` using `Activeperl ppm UI`, I didn't find the package there. Then I downloaded the `LibXML` from some other source and copied the required files in `"C:\Perl64\lib"` and `"C:\Perl64\site\lib"`.

I am using perl 5, version 20.
How can I make it work ?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Activeperl has definitely got XML::Twig. `ppm install XML::Twig` will install it, and that's still a much better parser than XML::Simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML::Simple problem is just a misunderstanding of syntax. Looks like you realise that you need to use `%` to dereference a hash reference, but you don't realise that you need to put the expression which returns the hash reference in a small `{ ... }` block.

So where you have:

```
%$ref->{version}
```

you actually want:

```
%{$ref->{version}}
```

Oh, and it's slightly worse than that. You have an extra `{ ... }` around that expression - so you're explicitly turning the expression back into a hash reference. What you want is:

```
foreach my $k (keys %{$ref->{version}})
```

Each value you get back in `$k`will be a hash key. And hash keys are always strings. So your call to `Dumper` in the next line is unnecessary too.

Comment: ok so my xml file is like "<Install>
<version number="6.0" build="latest" />
</Install>" so how I am supposed to read the values of number and build ??

Comment: If you have a new question, then please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

[XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) is a XS module, so just copying the sources (or even the compiled files) doesn't usually work. You have to install it properly.

The syntax `%$ref->{version}` is strange. Do you mean

```
%{ $ref->version }
```

or something else? Can you show [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper)'s `Dumper($ref)`?